# simple python3 script (openCV) does not run from Bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, numpy, opencv

i have following python3 OpenCV script to crop an image. If i run it from the python file everything is ok.

```
#reshaper.py
import argparse
import imutils
import numpy
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
roi = image[150:500, 150:520] 
cv2.imwrite(args["image"], roi)
```

but if put the command to run it from a bash file like this:

```
python3 reshaper.py -i filename.png;
```

then I get:
  File "reshaper.py", line 13, in 
    roi = image[150:500, 150:520] 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I would like later to include a for loop in the bash script, to reshape all files in the directory.

Why do i get an error by running through the bash script?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i changed my bash script to

```
for filename in *.png; do
    python3 BacteriaCounter.py -i $filename;
done
```

and it works!

Comment: You could improve your script by surrounding `$filename` in double quotes like this `"$filename"` then it will still work if you have spaces in your filenames. You could also accept a list of filenames as parameters and process multiple files inside your Python... it won't matter much initially, but if you later process thousands files you will be glad that you don't need to fire up a whole new Python interpreter for every single file.